# google play dev console - how to run firebase test labs instrumentation tests directly?

Tags: android, firebase, google-developers-console, firebase-test-lab

i see on the [firebase project site](https://console.firebase.google.com/) i that we are run android instrumentation tests when choosing **test lab** menu option:

[image]

Now i am searching for a way to run test labs instrumentation tests directly from google play developer console at the time of new apk upload.  I see that its automatically running a firebase robo test but i dont see an option where it can run my espresso instrumentation tests. Can you help me to find it?  I dont want to have to go to open firebase test labs from the firebase console and run it from there as its a nuisance to the business.  Prefer it all in one place so business does not forget to run the instrumentation tests.  I was actually thinking since the apk contains espresso test and production code that apks that google dev console would just run the test automatically but i dont see any provisions for that.

if you check the [docs here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270?hl=en#test&custom&crashes&performance&screenshots&security&new&previous&pre_launch_report&signin&languages&) it says we should be able to click on run custom tests. and indeed under the settings tab is a button for run custom tests. But it just goes to firebase test labs.  that means we have to manually upload a apk and test apk. Imagine the tests pass, then i again have to take that same apk and upload it to google play store. this is inefficient doing the same thing twice.

[image]

> Optional: Create a custom test with Firebase Test Lab for Android
>   With Firebase Test Lab, you can pay to select your device type and testing method to create custom tests. Custom test results will be available in your Firebase console.

To run a custom test:

- > Sign in to your Play Console. Select an app. Select Release
  >   management > Pre-launch report. At the top of your screen, you'll see 
  >   "Run Custom Tests" if you're able to run a custom test. To begin,
  >   select Get started.

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy. Setup your Android Studio project on Firebase using the Firebase Assistant (Tools>Firebase). Once done, run the tests and make sure that the device selection window opens up. Open the Cloud Testing tab in that and run the tests.[image]

I don't have that setup right now, but it works.

Comment: yah i saw this. but i want to run it from google play dev console. what i want to do is give the business an apk and they upload it and run the tests. without going into android studio. i updated my question so i yo u can see the google dev site should allow this provision.

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess you'll have to link your Firebase account to the Google Play account, then set up the project and launch the apk test with the correct matrix. I'm not sure for this one, never tried it. Sorry!